# STL iterator: Assertion Error

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, erase

Why does the following code produce an assertion error: `Expression: list iterators incompatible`?

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    list<int>::iterator iter=a.begin();
    a.erase(iter);

    iter==a.end();
}
```

Comment: This would have been fine if you wrote `iter=a.end()` since you have replaced the invalidated iterator, but since you wrote `iter==a.end()` you are comparing an invalidated iterator which leads to the incompatible warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

```
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    list<int>::iterator iter=a.begin();
    iter = a.erase(iter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An iterator on a given collection `a` becomes invalid when `a` changes, e.g. by removing an element.

Comment: That isn't true for all iterators in all types of container.

Comment: Which type of container isn't true?

Comment: You may `pop_back()` my `std::vector` collection `a` without my iterator pointing to somewhere in the middle of `a` skipping a beat. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

When erasing `iter` it got invalidated. I think invalid iterator can't be used for anything other than assigning to them, not even comparing them with anything. You might have wanted to use

```
iter = a.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

the iterator is invalid after the erase. in your case erase itself returns (you drop it) the end iterator as you were deleting the last element